# Contacting apple for a one off (per year) expedited review

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got a major bug in my app and I'm know you can contact apple for a one off / once per year Expedited review of your app to get it online quicker than normal.

My renewal is up in may for my apple dev account.

I'm just wondering if I contact them now if I'll get another at the end of may or if I have to wait 12 months ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can contact them as often as you want in my experience.

If you give them a good reason, they'll often be nice to you - but obviously it's not something to abuse. Do you have a reference / link for the once-a-year thing as that's news to us so I'm wondering if we missed something.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard, just send an email to appreview@apple.com and tell them your situation and that you need an expedited review and they'll try to accommodate you if it's reasonable.

Comment: I once released an app with NSZombieEnabled = YES.  They expedited the review for the update fix, but did make sure to remind me they were doing me a favor.

Comment: It always seems Apple lets you know they 'do you a solid' whenever you request something.. or maybe thats just my experience.

Comment: Note: that email isn't going to get you anywhere anymore. Try this link: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/index.html